# Playing videos MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I stream a video stored in the database on an [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) Razor website? I understand that @Video (Microsoft.Web.Helper) can be used to play static video files, however my files are actually in the database. Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `FileAction` that returns a stream to the file you're trying to play the video for, and then use that url for your video helper to use.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. This is what I did.

I created a http handler which wrote the video byte array into the response.

In the view, I wrote the below code:

```
@Video.MediaPlayer(path: ViewBag.VideoPath)
```

where ViewBag.VideoPath was set in the controller action as shown below.

```
 ViewBag.VideoPath = strBaseUrl + myObject.objectId.ToString() + ".video";
```